# ¿Cómo saber si mi código es optimo?

Tags: c#, optimización

muy buenas hoy andaba haciendo un reto de programación en c# e hice esto

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string encrypted;
        Encrypt(Console.ReadLine(),out encrypted);
        Console.WriteLine(encrypted);
    }
    public static bool Encrypt(string Text, out string encryptedText)
    { 
        List<char> numbers = new List<char>();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(Text,@"\d"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
            {
                if ((i<Text.Length-1)&&Char.IsLower(Text[i]) && Char.IsUpper(Text[i+1]))
                {
                    char[] aux= { Text[i], Text[i+1] };
                    Text = Text.Remove(i,2);
                    Text = Text.Insert(i,"*");
                    Text = Text.Insert(i,aux[0].ToString());
                    Text = Text.Insert(i,aux[1].ToString());
                    i += 2;
                }
                if(Char.IsDigit(Text[i]) && Text[i] != '0')
                {
                    numbers.Add(Text[i]);
                    Text = Text.Remove(i, 1);
                    Text = Text.Insert(i, "0");
                }
            }
            numbers.ForEach(item => Text = Text.Insert(0,item.ToString()));
            encryptedText = Text;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            encryptedText = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

el código consiste en encriptar un mensaje cambiando las letras de posición si el elemento [i] es minúscula y el elemento [i+1] es mayúscula y se agrega un * después y si hay un numero lo cambia por un cero y manda los números originales al principio del string.

Había pensado primero en crear un nuevo string que se vaya llenando conforme va leyendo el mensaje pero me di cuenta que ocupa que se actualice el tamaño cada vez que agrega un * o un 0 pero no se ¿Cuál manera es mas optima?.

este es el otro código.

```
public static bool Encrypt(string Text, out string encryptedText)
    {
        List<char> aux= Text.ToList();
        List<char> numbers = new List<char>();
        if (Regex.IsMatch(Text,@"\d"))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++)
            {

                if ((i<Text.Length-1)&&(Char.IsLower(Text[i]) && Char.IsUpper(Text[i+1])))
                {
                    aux[i] = Text[i + 1];
                    aux[i + 1] = Text[i];
                    Text=Text.Insert(i + 2, "*");
                    aux.Capacity++;
                    aux[i + 2] = '*';
                    i += 2;
                }
                if(Char.IsDigit(Text[i]) && Text[i] != '0')
                {
                    numbers.Add(Text[i]);
                    aux.Capacity++;
                    aux[i] = '0';
                    i++;
                }
            }
            Text = new string(aux.ToArray());
            numbers.ForEach(item => Text = Text.Insert(0,item.ToString()));
            encryptedText = Text;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            encryptedText = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Y por qué no guardas los milisegundos al inicio y final del código, restas y sabes cuánto le cuesta ejecutar cada código? Córrelo digamos 1000 veces cada uno y tendrás una media bastante decente para saber cuál está más optimizado

Comment: eso sale de codewars no? si no recuerdo mal, lo resolvi usando un stringbuilder, que sirven justamente para eso, para armar strings de esa forma, sin el overhead de una lista...

Comment: Porque tienes que preguntar en un `if` por `(i<Text.Length-1)` esto no es necesario si usas `for (int i = 0; i <= Text.Length-1; i++)` aplica ese restar directo en el loop cuando iteras

Comment: Podrias evaluar usar un `StringBuilder` por lo general es mas performante que las listas de char. Tambien valida sino puede usar la librerias de `Task Parallel` con un `Parallel.ForEach()` se puede usar todos los nucleos del procesador, aunque bueno hay que ver sino aparecen otros problemas como ser la concurrencia https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl

Comment: @LeandroTuttini lo pongo asi porque necesito verificar el ultimo carácter para ver si no es un numero y si es una minúscula no se salga del rango